# How can I get a webapp to exit gracefully if I delete it's deployment while it has a thread running?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, weblogic

I have a Spring MVC webapp, that as part of its operation runs off and performances several SQL queries, that can take up to 15 minutes to run.

If you delete the deployment while a query is running, the weblogic log will print the following stacktrace:

```
POST /MyWebapp/submitQuery HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-nz
Referer: http://server:1111/mywebapp/
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Length: 268
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=KgJ5VnFLpWTp1ZNjwt3p1D4FHxmSQnPpTTwX18TDyMxnpgGBXWTD!1657710130; ADMINCONSOLESESSION=tSWjVnXJb6MPn0Bj9h4FPWvyzHC5pbCf2H20ZgfGHLTKpykMN82m!802748838

]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/DefaultThrowableRenderer
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.debug(Log4JLogger.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:989)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

If you wait for queries to finish before deleting the deployment, then the errors will not be posted.

I've been told that it's not acceptable for this stacktrace to be thrown.

Two questions:

1. What actually happens if you delete a deployment while a thread is running?
2. How can I get Weblogic to handle it gracefully?

Comment: Why can't you call `Stop when work completes`, wait for the app to stop gracefully, and then delete it? You have a requirement to delete a running app AND not throw an error? Seems difficult. You may want to look at this for ideas: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_weblogic_starting_stopping_applications_jmx.htm

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing - Stop when work completes might be a perfectly acceptable solution.