# What happens when a weblogic deployment is deleted?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, memory, web-applications, weblogic

I'm trying to reproduce an error, and I'm having difficulty doing it.

Essentially, what I'm doing is:

1. Deploy a Spring MVC webapp.
2. Submit a query to the webapp, which calls a thread sleep for five minutes.
3. In that time delete the webapp deployment from Weblogic.

What I'm expecting is for the webapp to throw a `NoClassDefFound` stacktrace in its logs.

eg.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/DefaultThrowableRenderer
at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.debug(Log4JLogger.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:989)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

Instead what's happening is that the webapp finishes executing fine:

Here's the code:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class WeblogicFail {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(WeblogicFail.class);



    public WeblogicFail()
    {

    }


    @Autowired
    AaBean ab;


    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public void submitQuery(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException
    {

        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60);

        MyContainer mc = ab.someMethod();
        logger.debug(mc.toString());

        MyContainer mc2 = new MyContainer("aaaaa");
        logger.debug(mc2.toString());

         res.getOutputStream().write(("helloworld"+System.currentTimeMillis()).getBytes());
         res.getOutputStream().flush();
         res.getOutputStream().close();



    }
}

@Component
public class AaBean {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AaBean.class);


    public MyContainer someMethod()
    {

        logger.debug("some method start");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000*60*10);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        logger.debug("some method about to return");
        return new MyContainer("here's a container");


    }

}

public class MyContainer {


    private String s;

    public MyContainer(String s) {
        super();
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.s + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

WeblogicFail-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mytestspace" />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Logger is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

and Spring Framework is `3.2.0.RELEASE`.

What I'm expecting here is for the logs to print:

```
09:11:50 DEBUG AaBean:19 - some method start
09:21:50 DEBUG AaBean:27 - some method about to return
```

And then to get the stack trace in the the domain level logs.

Instead it continues executing fine, logs the following two:

```
09:21:50 DEBUG WeblogicFail:62 - here's a container1437427310939
09:21:50 DEBUG WeblogicFail:65 - aaaaa1437427310939
```

and returns the correct string to the browser.

If I've deleted the deployment, how does it know where to find the the class definition etc?

I've tried forcing garbage collection [as per here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/monitoring/RequestGarbageCollection.html), but it continues to operate successfully.

This question isn't a duplicate to the other question - as this one is asking what happens to the objects when a deployment is deleted.

Comment: Another option is to do a redeploy without the delete, it will wait until calls are finished and retire the old app: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm#DEPGD258 Deleting a production deployment is almost never going to work how you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a webapp to exit gracefully if I delete it's deployment while it has a thread running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465118/how-can-i-get-a-webapp-to-exit-gracefully-if-i-delete-its-deployment-while-it-h)